# TSQL derived column with date convert that checks for non-date convertible strings

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion

I have a date column with dates stored as strings, such as 20120817. Unfortunately, the text form field that populates this column is free text, so I cannot guarantee that an occasional "E" or "whatever" shows up in this column. And more than a few already have.

What I need to do is convert the string column into a date column. Of course the convert will reject the random string characters. Is there any way to create a derived column that will not only convert the strings but exclude the non-date convertible strings?

If there were no non-date convertible strings in the table, the following would work:

```
ADD [convertedDate] AS CONVERT(DATE, [stringDate], 102)
```

And it does work perfectly in a test table I created. But when I introduce other non-convertible strings, I receive the dreaded "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" error for obvious reasons.

Is there a function that will catch non-convertible elements that I can add on to this derived column code? Or is a view or function the only - or best - way to handle this? I played around with IsDate() with little luck.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a pattern to the non `20120817` type date fields?

Comment: Yes, they're 99% in the form 20120817 with a few stragglers of 20086 and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a function called `ISDATE(date)`, maybe you can use it in a CASE statement or in the WHERE part of the query... It depends on how you're doing it, maybe something like this

```
ADD [convertedDate] AS CASE WHEN ISDATE([stringDate]) = 1 THEN CONVERT(DATE,[stringDate], 102) ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a try... thank you! I've tried variations on this but haven't found a form that SSMS likes yet.

Comment: Sorry, didn't tested it only wrote what come up to my mind, maybe you can just add the new column as datetime and after that update it with the case statement

Comment: This seems to be working... anything that can't be directly converted to a DATE is coming up NULL, which is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2012 you can make use of the try_convert function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx

It will work normally if the conversion succeeds but return null if the conversion fails

ADD [convertedDate] AS TRY_CONVERT(DATE, [stringDate], 102)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out... but I'm on 2008 R2, unfortunately... but I'll know for when we upgrade at some point

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some ideas...

```
DECLARE @date1 varchar(50)
DECLARE @date2 varchar(50)
SET @date1 = '20120101'
SET @date2 = 'e20120101'

SELECT
ISDATE(@date1),
ISDATE(@date2),
CASE WHEN ISDATE(@date1) = 1 THEN CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,@date1) END,
CASE WHEN ISDATE(@date2) = 1 THEN CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,@date2) END
```